# RecyclerView StaggeredGridLayoutManager reordering issue

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to display three (at least that's the case I have an issue with) items in a `RecyclerView` with a `StaggeredGridLayoutManager` with two columns. The first item is spanned across the two rows. Here's how it looks like:

[image: Correct initial behaviour]

Now, I'm moving the item "Item 2" to top. Here's the code I call, in the adapter (it's a sample I wrote to demonstrate the issue I have in a more complex project):

```
private int findById(int id) {
    for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); ++i) {
        if (items.get(i).title.equals("Item " + id)) {
            return i;
        }
    }

    return -1;
}

// Moving the item "Item 2" with id = 2 and position = 0
public void moveItem(int id, int position) {
    final int idx = findById(id);
    final Item item = items.get(idx);

    if (position != idx) {
        items.remove(idx);
        items.add(position, item);
        notifyItemMoved(idx, position);
        //notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

After that, the array is fine: `[Item 2, Item 1, Item 3]`. However, the view is far from fine:

[image: Layout issue]

If I touch the `RecyclerView` (enough to trigger the overscroll effect if there's not enough items to scroll), Item 2 move to the left, where I expected to see it in the first place (with a nice animation):

[image: Expected result]

As you maybe saw in the code, I tried to replace `notifyItemMoved(idx, position)` by a call to `notifyDataSetChanged()`. It works, but the change is not animated.

I wrote a complete sample to demonstrate this and put it on [GitHub](https://github.com/Kernald/android-recyclerview-staggeredgridlayoutmanager-issue). It's nearly minimal (there are options to move the item and toggle their spanning).

I don't see what I can be doing wrong. Is this a bug with `StaggeredGridLayoutManager`? I would like to avoid `notifyDataSetChanged()` as I would like to keep consistency regarding the animations.

---

Edit: after some digging, there's no need for a fully-spanned item to show the issue. I removed the full-span. When I try to move Item 2 to position 0, it *doesn't move*: Item 1 goes after it, and Item 3 is moved on the right, so I have: empty cell, Item 2, new line, Item 1, Item 3. I still have the correct layout after a scroll.

What's more interesting is that I don't have the issue with a `GridLayoutManager`. I need a full-span item so it's not a solution, but I guess it's indeed a bug in the `StaggeredGridLayoutManager`…

Comment: I dont know if this is a bug or not but I have seen this too, things only seem to move when you scroll and the `gap strategy` is checked

Comment: @tyczj: `GAP_HANDLING_NONE` avoids the moving items, but I still get an incorrect disposition. `GAP_HANDLING_MOVE_ITEMS_BETWEEN_SPANS` is probably the default, anyway, I have the same behaviour with it than without specifying anything.

Comment: Yes I know I am just saying that after you scroll the adapter checks the gaps and then moves things to the correct place

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I don't have a complete answer, but I can point you to both a workaround and the bug report (that I believe is related).

The trick to updating the layout so that it looks like your second screenshot, is to call `invalidateSpanAssignments()` on the `StaggeredGridLayoutManger` (sglm) after you've called `notifyItemMoved()`.  The "challenge" is that if you call it immediately after `nIM()`, it won't run.  If you delay the call for a few ms, it will.  So, in your referenced code for MainActivity, I've made your `sglm` a private field:

```
private StaggeredGridLayoutManager sglm;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    adapter = new Adapter();
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    sglm = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(sglm);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

And down in the switch block, reference it in a handler:

```
        case R.id.move_sec_top:
            adapter.moveItem(2, 0);
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    sglm.invalidateSpanAssignments();
                }
            }, 100);
            return true;
```

The result is that your animation still runs, the layout ends up the way you want it.  This is a real kludge, but it does work.  I believe this is the same bug that I found and reported at the following link:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=93156

While my "symptom" and required call were different, the underlying issue seems to be identical.

Good luck!

**EDIT:  No need to postDelayed**, simply posting will do the trick:

```
        case R.id.move_sec_top:
            adapter.moveItem(2, 0);
            new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    sglm.invalidateSpanAssignments();
                }
            });
            return true;
```

My original theory was that the call was blocked until the layout pass was over, but I believe that is not the case.  Instead, I now think that if you call `invalidateSpanAssignments()` immediately, it actually executes too soon (before the layout changes have completed).  So, the post above (without delay) simply adds the call to the end of the rendering queue where it happens after the layout.

Comment: Sounds a reasonable explanation. I'll take a look at it tomorrow, thanks!

Comment: The bug has been acknowledged by Google: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=93711#c1

Your workaround works fine in the meantime, so I'll accept this.

Comment: Any ideas on how to animate the span assignment invalidation?

Comment: Google is taking a VERY LONG time to fix this issue... By now, this layout manager is unusable.

Comment: @mato I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "animate the span assignment invalidation"?  What I've seen is that, as long as the handler/post workaround (above) is used, the appropriate layout events and animations will occur.  Are you asking if one can control the duration over which an item grows/shrinks when it's span count changes?

Comment: @MojoTosh No. This is what I'm trying to do: I have 3 view modes on my action bar that the user can select to see different layouts on the `RecyclerView`. All these 3 modes are using the `StaggeredGridLayoutManager`, but all with different layouts for the children views. So whenever the user changes the view mode, I'm calling `notifyDatasetChanged()`. If the user scrolled the content previously, and the changes the view mode, the new mode is positioned at the previous item position, which is good. But then, is the user scrolls to the top, sometimes he can see the gap that is not being covered.

Comment: @MojoTosh ... so I had to set an `OnScrollListener` to see when the scroll finishes and do the workaround by posting the `invalidateSpanAssignments()` in the message queue. But when I do that, there is no animation at all; the items are positioned again in just one frame, which looks REALLY bad.

I don't know if that explained my issue a little better. Anyway, thanks for your interest! :)

Comment: @mato I think I understand what you're trying to do now, and have two recommendations. First, post a new question on SO with some minimal source showing this.  There's not enough space in the comments to do this justice, I think you'll get a better response that way.  Second, think about notifyDatasetChanged() as the "nuclear option", to be avoided if possible, because this tells RV/SGLM "forget everything and rebuild from scratch".  It's unlikely that any stock animation will apply after this call.  If you do create a new SO question, let me know.  Hope that helps.

Comment: @MojoTosh I get what you say about the `notifiyDatasetChanged`, but I'm calling it when I change the view mode, and not when the scrolling reached the top. At that specific moment, I need the gap to be filled with existing items, with the stock animation. And that's what's not working sometimes... It's definitely a bug and it's not related to `notifyDatasetChanged`, at least in my case. Unfortunately, I cannot post any source code, as it is not mine and has a copyright. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

Well I have done this way.

```
StaggeredGridLayoutManager gaggeredGridLayoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
gaggeredGridLayoutManager.setGapStrategy(StaggeredGridLayoutManager.GAP_HANDLING_MOVE_ITEMS_BETWEEN_SPANS);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(gaggeredGridLayoutManager);

dataList = YourDataList (Your Code for Arraylist);

recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
recyclerAdapter = new DataAdapter(dataList, recyclerView);
recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter);

// Magic line
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new ScrollListener());
```

Create class for Custom **RecyclerView Scroll Listener**.

```
private class ScrollListener extends RecyclerView.OnScrollListener {
   @Override
   public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
        gaggeredGridLayoutManager.invalidateSpanAssignments();
   }
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks, but the fix has been released by Google in support libraries 22 and newer. It now works out of the box with the code I wrote in the original question.